# reduce memory that tomcat is using

Tags: java, tomcat8, taskmanager

I am using tomcat for my web application. I am starting server from services. I have this configuration:
-Xms256m;-Xmx512m;-XX:PermSize=256m;-XX:MaxPermSize=512M

When I change this configuration and restart service and check in task manager, how much memory it is using, it is showing that it is using the same memory every time.

Note: I am using tomcat 8 on 64 bit windows machine.

Comment: Are you changing the configuration in the correct place?

Comment: I am changing in service.bat file. I didn't find these parameters in any other files.

Comment: Which column of task manager are you referring for memory ?

Comment: In details tab there is a column "Memory(Private Memory Set)"